# Jar compile: how to exclude some folders during making jar

Tags: java, jar

I have some Mercurial subrepos in my sources, and so, there's ".hg" dir for each subrepo.

During making jar, this dirs ".hg" becomes packed into jar. How can i exclude this files?

I use Java ME Platform SDK 3.0, i tried to add "filter.excludes=**/.hg" to nbproject/project.properties, but there's no effect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it: filter `**/.hg/**` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try with filter **/*.hg this will correspond to all the subdirectories.

Comment: No, `*/.hg` does not work. I just found the solution: filter `**/.hg/**` does the trick. Unfortunately i can't answer to my own question right now, so, i'll do it as soon as i can.